# Resizable Java component

Tags: java, resize, components

I would like to have a Java component which has a resize icon on the bottom right of the component so that when I drag that icon, the component will automatically resize with it.

By resize icon, I mean the following:

[image: resize icon in Google Talk]

The above image contains the resize icon in the Google Talk messenger's main window. Is there any Java component which provides this facility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will find in this article how to add an icon looking like the resize icon you are referring to.

[image: PixelPushing] [PixelPushing](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2005/06/07/pixelpushing.html)

[image: Google Talk Styled Form]

Answer (score 0):

the JStatusBar ?

Comment: I have not seen a java component called JStatusBar. Was that added after Java 1.4?

Answer (score 0):

ummm
putting an image there is not hard... the resizing is. you'll want to use (once you have some sort of button) code like this:

```
private void buttonMousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
        sx = evt.getX();
        sy = evt.getY();
}

private void buttonMouseDragged(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
        if(!evt.isMetaDown()){
                Point p = getLocation();

                locX = p.x + evt.getX()-sx;
                locY = p.y + evt.getY()-sy;
                setLocation(locX, locY);
        }
}
```

...except instead of Setlocation you'll want to use something like setBounds or setSize... and you'll have to modify the code a bit. What I have is for dragging it, but the principle is the same.

Comment: I have implemented the functionality using the approach given in the 'accepted answer'. I wanted to know whether if there was already a resizable java component so that I am not reinventing the wheel.
:)